# How to write base case for this recursive function that removes children of nodes that hold odd keys?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, recursive-datastructures

Here's the code I have so far, I thought returning it out of the function if my condition wasn't met would work but its stack overflowing...I know that I need to establish a base case but not really how....

```
 public void removeOddSubtrees() {
   if (root == null) {
     return;
   }
   removeOddSubtrees(root);
 }
 private void removeOddSubtrees(Node root) {    
   removeOddSubtrees(root);
   if (root.key % 2 != 0) {
     root.right = null;
     root.left = null;
     root = null;
    } else {
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the issue?  Where does it say that it's throwing the exception?  (Why are you calling the recursive method *before* determining if it's an odd keyed node?)

Comment: i dont really have a base case i dont think...the exception is on "removeOddSubtrees(root)"

Answer (score 0):

i changed my helper function to the following, and i think it may be working now:

```
private void removeOddSubtrees(Node root){
        if(root != null){
        removeOddSubtrees(root.left);
        removeOddSubtrees(root.right);
        if(root.key % 2 != 0){
            root.right = null;
            root.left = null;
            root = null;
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the code that you posted in the answer does work, but there are some simplifications that can be applied to it. Here's how I'd write it:

```
 private void removeOddSubtrees(Node root) {    
   if (root == null) {
     return;
   }

   if (root.key % 2 != 0) {
     root.right = null;
     root.left = null;
     return;
   }

   removeOddSubtrees(root.left);
   removeOddSubtrees(root.right);
}
```

First, I am usually checking the exit condition at the very top and exit the method immediately. That is, my condition does a `return` if `root == null`.

Second, there is no need to do `root = null` if `root.key % 2 != 0`. it actually has no effect: it places `null` in the parameter that the function receives but as this parameter is not used after that in this method then no one will ever see this `null`. Note that also the calling code will not be affected. assignment to parameters do not propagate outside of the called method.

Finally, I think it makes more sense to call  `removeOddSubtrees()` on `root.left` and `root.right` only if the key is even. when the key is odd you are removing the left and right subtrees from the tree so doing a recursive call on these subtrees is probably meaningless as this entire subtree will be removed from the tree shortly after. Thus, in my code I do the recursive calls only if the key is even.